# ¿Como destruir o reinicializar una iteracion (loop) de un setInterval jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

En un gestor de gráficos dinámicos tengo la siguiente funcion

```
function test(id_que, i, setTime){      
        initSetInterval = window.setInterval(function(){
            myFunction(id_que, i);  
        }, setTime);
    }
```

Yo selecciono cualquier base de datos y esta me retorna unos querys, la funcion `test` recibe el **`id_que` (que es el id_del_query)**, **`i` (que es el id_del_grafico)**, **`setTime` (que es el tiempo que se refresca cada grafico)**.....

**PROBLEMA**

La base de datos 1 me trae 3 querys y al momento de hacer el `change` hacia la base de datos 2 esta me retorna un solo `query`, hasta ahi bien si hago un `console.log(id_que, i, setTime)` **antes de ejecutar el `setInterval`**, una vez se ejecuta cuando hago los cambios de base de datos el `setInterval` se queda ejecutando la petición de ambas conexiones.

> ¿Como podria evitar eso?, puesto que que al momento de hacer dichos
>   cambios de base de datos obtiene el `id_de_la_conexion` pero se queda con
>   el `id_del_query` que obtiene de cada conexion

***Eje:***

```
id_conn: 1, id_que: 6
id_conn: 1, id_que: 7
id_conn: 1, id_que: 8
id_conn: 2, id_que: 3
id_conn: 2, id_que: 6 // No existe
id_conn: 2, id_que: 7 // No existe
id_conn: 2, id_que: 8 // No existe
```

Answer (score 0):

En el `change` hacia la base de datos 2 necesitas desactivar el intervalo, puesto que este nunca se detiene a menos que se diga lo contrario:

```
clearInterval(initSetInterval);
```

Claro, si necesitas asegurarte que las conexiones se ejecutaron correctamente, ahí se puede complicar un poco, pero para eliminar esa discrepancia con ese comando basta.

Si necesitas controlar el número de ejecuciones te recomiendo más que utilices `setTimeout` en lugar de `setInterval` de ser posible

Comment: Hola Belhenix, gracias por tu aporte, pero bien lo dices ya he verificado bien los datos que recibela funcion y son precisos, el problema esta es precisamente en ese setInterval he usado clearInterval y no me funciona, y el problema del SetTimeOut es que este solo se ejecutara una vez y la idea es que se me este ejecutando constantemente con los tiempos que se le han sido asigandos a cada grafico.